# How to add keyboard shortcut to flex-project to focus container browser?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

Learning flex,

What would be the appropriate way to add some AS in a flex-project, giving giving
focus back to the parent browser.

```
ctrl-q: i'm blurring flash
ctrl-t: ah, a new browser tab.
```

regards,
//t

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following handler, as a callback for a capturing listener of the `KeyboadEvent.KEY_DOWN`, might suffice:

```
private function handleKeyDown (event:KeyboardEvent):void {

  if (event.ctrlKey) {

    switch(event.keyCode) {
      case Keyboard.T:
        event.stopPropagation();

        // open new tab
        navigateToURL(new URLRequest("about:blank"), "_blank");
        break;

      case Keyboard.Q:
        event.stopPropagation();

        // remove focus
        if(ExternalInterface.available) {
          ExternalInterface.call("document." + ExternalInterface.objectID + ".blur");
        }
        break;

    }
  }
}
```

I say *might* because I can't guarantee you won't have to do something extra to get all browsers to behave the same.